# Generate an E-R Diagram by reverse-engineering a database

Tags: database, diagram, entity-relationship

*Note: Originally this question was asked for PostgreSQL, however, the answer applies to almost any database which has a JDBC driver that can detect foreign-key associations.*

---

Querying PostgreSQL data dictionary for foreign-keys and relationship between tables is very straightforward, but how can I use that information to generate a graph of the relations between tables?

Any recommendations about tools that can do this?

**EDIT:** I know GraphVIZ/DOT *can* be useful, however, I don't know have any idea regarding how to code an app that would generate the directed graph .DOT file.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099444/generate-er-diagram-from-existing-postgresql-database

Comment: See a complete example from command line on perl here https://gist.github.com/albfan/4fcf4240860fa73811b4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dot is part of the [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) package, which is a pretty damn cool/useful tool. Of course, you'll need something to generate the dot files for graphviz. I've used [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) once or twice in the past, and it works pretty well, provided you have the relationships defined in the database.

Comment: Yay, SchemaSpy looks like the right tool for the job! Thanks :)

Comment: Even though there are no updates during last few years this tool still works just fine.

Comment: SchemaSpy is quite awesome. Confirming that it works with SQL Server!

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Visio will easily do this.

Comment: As of Visio 2013 it doesn't anymore, they've removed the database diagramming from an existing DB.

Comment: Such a pity. I have been using that function regularly for the last 6 years or so.

Answer (score 2):

At least for Oracle I run this query or ask the DBA to run it and send me the results. Results can be copied directly to a text file to be interpreted by Graphviz's tools, resulting in a database diagram.

```
SELECT '"' || Source.TABLE_NAME || '" -> "' 
           || Destiny.TABLE_NAME || '";' AS For_GraphViz
FROM dba_constraints Source
JOIN dba_constraints Destiny
ON Source.owner='my_db_owner' AND Destiny.owner='my_db_owner'
AND Source.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='R'
-- theoretically this validation should be redundant
-- AND Destiny.Constraint_type = 'P'
AND Source.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = Destiny.CONSTRAINT_NAME
ORDER BY Source.TABLE_NAME, Source.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, Source.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , Source.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME, Source.INDEX_NAME;
```

A similar query can be created easily for SQL Server, don't know about MySQL, PostgreSQL et al.

Comment: By the way, I *strongly* suggest using "circo" or "twopi" to plot the diagram as opposed to plain "dot" or even "neato" - at least in my experience produces much pleasant graphical results for DBs with several hundred tables.

Answer (score 1):

[Dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) is multiplatform and may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) is also a free and nice alternative.