# Build ER-diagram from an existing database

Tags: postgresql, reverse-engineering, pgadmin

How can I build the ER-Diagram from a database. I am using PostgreSQL and pgAdmin3 on Linux.

Comment: Please elaborate on "reverse engineer".

Comment: ok I want to build an ER Diagram from the existing database.

Comment: Have a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185967/generate-an-e-r-diagram-by-reverse-engineering-a-database