# Java error while using schemaspy

Tags: java, schemaspy

I have a big database on MSSQL but no schema... after reading [Generate an E-R Diagram by reverse-engineering a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185967/generate-an-e-r-diagram-by-reverse-engineering-a-database) I've decided to try schemaspy, but it doesn't want to start because of Java:
[image]

AFAIK its a matter of java version: I've tried latest 7u21, then older 6u43 and 6u31... same thing. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Latest should be sufficient - when you install the latest runtime, try typing java -version to ensure that you are actually using the latest version of the runtime prior to running the program. Does the product website list any requirements?

Comment: Just make sure that you checking `JRE` (Java Run-Time) versions and not `JDK`'s.

Comment: Java class version 49.0 is from java5 so any of the mentioned versions are fine. But you can use `java -version` to figure out the version you're using in fact.